# Convert List of Maps into Single Map In Groovy

Tags: list, dictionary, groovy

I have a list of map like below:

```
List mapOne = [[hi:1], [hello:2],[xyx:4]]
```

This map should be converted to one single map like below

```
Map resultMap=[hi:1, hello:2,xyx:4]
```

Do we have any built in functions in Groovy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just do:

```
Map resultMap = mapOne.collectEntries()
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is `sum`:

```
groovy:000> [[hi:1], [hello:2], [xyx:4]].sum()
===> [hi:1, hello:2, xyx:4]
```

Comment: clever and simple use of sum() +1

Comment: @PabloPazos Yet, i'd only use it for golfing. `collectEntries()` is the idiomatic groovy way.

Comment: even though it works perfectly and is a clever use of sum() :)